# How to merge two multidimensional arrays and adjust existing values?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I would like to put together the following arrays and calculate best prices.

```
$pricesForAllCustomer = array(
    array(
        'from' => '600',
        'to' => 'any',
        'price' => 0.15
    )
);
```

```
$customerSpecificPrices = array (
    array(
        'from' => '1',
        'to' => '1799',
        'price' => 0.17
    ),
    array(
        'from' => '1800',
        'to' => 'any',
        'price' => 0.14
    )
);
```

How can I combine these 2 arrays to achieve the following result?

```
$calculatedBestOffers = array(
    array(
        'from' => '1',
        'to' => '599',
        'price' => 0.17
    ),
    array(
        'from' => '600',
        'to' => '1799',
        'price' => 0.15
    ),
    array(
        'from' => '1800',
        'to' => 'any',
        'price' => 0.14
    )
);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this yourself so far?

Comment: You mean merge not combine. [Read this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-array_merge-and-array_combine-in-PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to find the element whose `from` value is greater than `pricesForAllCustomer` `to` value and place it between these elements (assuming that `customerSpecificPrices` is already ordered.):

```
$pricesForAllCustomer = array(
    array(
        'from' => '600',
        'to' => 'any',
        'price' => 0.15
    )
);

$customerSpecificPrices = array (
    array(
        'from' => '1',
        'to' => '1799',
        'price' => 0.17
    ),
    array(
        'from' => '1800',
        'to' => 'any',
        'price' => 0.14
    )
);

$calculatedBestOffers = [];
$foundPos = false;
foreach($customerSpecificPrices as $key => $elem){
    if(!$foundPos && $pricesForAllCustomer[0]['from'] < $elem['from']){
        $calculatedBestOffers[$key-1]['to'] = $pricesForAllCustomer[0]['from']-1;
        $pricesForAllCustomer[0]['to'] = $elem['from']-1;
        $calculatedBestOffers[] = $pricesForAllCustomer[0];
        $calculatedBestOffers[] = $elem;
        $foundPos = true;
    }
    else $calculatedBestOffers[] = $elem;
}

print_r($calculatedBestOffers);
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => 1
            [to] => 599
            [price] => 0.17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => 600
            [to] => 1799
            [price] => 0.15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [from] => 1800
            [to] => any
            [price] => 0.14
        )

)
```